# Can I use more heap than 32 GB with compressed oops?

Tags: java, oop, optimization, compression

I could understand that, with compressed oops, we can only use 32 GB of RAM. Is there some way I can use more than that, like by allocating 2 heaps or something?

Comment: How about not using compressed oops?

Comment: I am trying to store a large amount of date value pair to the main memory for high speed access. Here i have applied many optimization such that at the end 80% of space is eaten up by the references rather than the actual data. In the quest to decrease the space occupied by the reference , i have discovered compressed oops.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't have multiple heaps (you can have multiple JVMs though, which is called scaling out as opposed to scaling up).

JVM uses compressed object pointers automatically below 32 GiB of memory. If you understand how it works (dropping youngest three bits from each address as they are always 0 due to memory alignment) you'll understand that you can't go further.

There is an interesting fact: once you exceed this 32 GiB border JVM will stop using compressed object pointers, effectively reducing the available memory. That means increasing your JVM heap above 32 GiB you must go way above. According to great [*Everything I Ever Learned about JVM Performance Tuning @twitter*](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/JVM-Performance-Tuning-twitter) (around 13:00) presentation **increasing heap from 32 GiB to anything below 48 GiB will actually decrease the amount of available memory** (!) because compressed object pointers are no longer there.

Comment: Well, it is not true that the break-even point is 48GiB. The exact number depends on how many pointers you hold in memory. And that is different for each application.

Comment: @RokKralj You are correct that the break-even will be dependent per application. For example, if your application is mostly "2G arrays of int" Aka, 8G, then you will see almost no difference in memory usage. For "normal" usage patterns however, you end up with a lot of extra overhead from the larger pointers.

Answer (score 10):

If you need more than 32 GB, I suggest you consider using some off heap memory.  This effectively gives you an additional memory space which doesn't use up much heap.

For example, I routinely use 200-800 GB but only 1-2 GB of that is heap. This means I have most efficient form of compressed Oops and virtually unlimited capacity. Note: there are three forms of compressed Oops,

- plain 32-bit unshifted (up to ~2 GB)
- 32-bit shifted (up to ~26 GB)
- 32-bit shifted and offset (up to ~32 GB)

Two ways of using off heap memory are direct memory ByteBuffers and memory mapped files.  Direct memory scale well up to about 3/4 of your main memory size.  Memory mapped files scale well up to the size of you hard drive space (which is typically much more)

> Here i have applied many optimization such that at the end 80% of space is eaten up by the references rather than the actual data.

That sounds like you are not using the most efficient data structures. You can use different data structures where data is more of the spaces used or at least 2/3rds.

Comment: "I routinely use 200-800 GB". I envy you... Is that virtual memory or backed by actual RAM?

Comment: @Thilo I use virtual memory as I only have 128 GB main memory, but some of my clients have between 512 GB and 3 TB of main memory.

Answer (score 7):

You can use larger heap sizes with an additional parameter: 
`-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=alignment`

This parameter is a fixed adjustment of Java objects. The default value is `8` (bytes). The indicated value has to be a power of two, and ranges from `8` to `256`.

The heap size limit in bytes is calculated as:

```
4GB * ObjectAlignmentInBytes
```

A 64GB heap size will be available for compressed pointers with the following line:

```
-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16
```

There is a note to be considered in the documentation for larger heap sizes though:

> Note: As the alignment value increases, the unused space between
>   objects will also increase. As a result, you may not realize any
>   benefits from using compressed pointers with large Java heap sizes.

Comment: What determines if you do or don't realize any benefits?

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I'd investigate each of the following:

1. Not using compressed oops.
2. Reducing your application's memory consumption (a memory profiler is an extremely handy tool for investigating memory usage).
3. Splitting the workload across multiple JVMs, each with a sub-32GB heap.

Each of the above has the potential for solving your problem. Which is the most appropriate is really hard for us to say.

> 80% of space is eaten up by the references rather than the actual data.

This sounds rather extreme. It may be worth revisiting your data structures, with the emphasis on reducing the number of object references. I've done things along these lines in the past, but it's very hard to give specific recommendations without knowing your problem and the data structures you're currently using.

Comment: I have 15000000000 date,value pairs to store. I have applied the best data structure to obtain the best performance but then the referance is what is eating the spaces. 2 JVM is something i thought about. If there are better ideas , let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the nature of the data?

The way to do this might be to store the data off the Java heap. You can do this by getting hold of some off-heap memory, typically using a [direct `ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct), and then storing data in it in the form of bytes. This has various advantages; the objects can be stored very compactly, you don't need to have a huge heap, and the objects won't be swept by the garbage collector. The disadvantage is the complexity, and the risk of memory leaks.

There are libraries which can help you do this, including:

- http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections
- http://directmemory.apache.org/