# JMock with(instanceOf(Integer.class)) does not compile in Java 8

Tags: generics, migration, java-8, hamcrest, jmock

After upgrading to Java 8. I now have compile errors of the following kind:

```
The method with(Matcher<Object>) is ambiguous for the type new Expectations(){}
```

It is caused by this method call:

```
import org.jmock.Expectations;

public class Ambiguous {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expectations expectations = new Expectations();
        expectations.with(org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf(Integer.class));
    }
}
```

It seems like with is returned from `instanceOf()` is ambiguous from what `with()` expects, or vice versa. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Exact JDK version? JMock version? And a complete source example would be helpful.

Comment: Probably you can add type to `instanceof`: `expectations.with(org.hamcrest.Matchers.<Integer>instanceOf(Integer.class))`.

Answer (score 2):

There is some easy ways to help the compiler.

assign the matcher to a local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Expectations expectations = new Expectations();
    Matcher<Integer> instanceOf = Matchers.instanceOf(Integer.class);
    expectations.with(instanceOf);
}
```

you can specify the type parameter with a type witness as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Expectations expectations = new Expectations();
    expectations.with(Matchers.<Integer>instanceOf(Integer.class));
}
```

wrap the instanceOf in your own type safe method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Expectations expectations = new Expectations();
    expectations.with(instanceOf(Integer.class));
}

public static <T> Matcher<T> instanceOf(Class<T> type) {
    return Matchers.instanceOf(type);
}
```

I prefer the last solution since it is reusable and the test remains easy to read.