# RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN issue in Java8

Tags: java, migration, java-8, rounding

I am using jdk 1.8.0_45, and our tests discovered a bug in rouding.
RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN works the same as RoundingMode.HALF_UP when the last decimal that decide the rounding is 5.

I found related issues with RoundingMode.HALF_UP, but they are fixed in update 40. I also put a bug to the oracle, but from my experience they are really unresponsive.

```
package testjava8;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Formatori {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0000");
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        Double toFormat = 10.55555;
        System.out.println("Round down");
        System.out.println(format.format(toFormat));

        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        toFormat = 10.55555;
        System.out.println("Round up");
        System.out.println(format.format(toFormat));
    }
}
```

Actual result:
Round down
10.5556
Round up
10.5556

Expected result(obtain with jdk 1.7):
Round down
10.5555
Round up
10.5556

Comment: That bug doesn't reproduce with jdk 1.8.0_45. And I read the issue that you said, but is not the same problem. That issue was fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that it's intended change. The JDK 1.7 behavior was incorrect.

The problem is that you simply *cannot* represent the number `10.55555` using the `double` type. It stores the data in IEEE binary format, so when you assign the decimal `10.55555` number to the `double` variable, you actually get the closest value which can be represented in IEEE format: `10.555550000000000210320649784989655017852783203125`. This number is bigger than `10.55555`, so it's correctly rounded to `10.5556` in `HALF_DOWN` mode.

You can check some numbers which can be exactly represented in binary. For example, `10.15625` (which is `10 + 5/32`, thus `1010.00101` in binary). This number is rounded to `10.1562` in `HALF_DOWN` mode and `10.1563` in `HALF_UP` mode.

If you want to restore the old behavior, you can first convert your number to `BigDecimal` using [`BigDecimal.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) constructor, which "translates a `double` into a `BigDecimal`, using the `double`'s canonical string representation":

```
BigDecimal toFormat = BigDecimal.valueOf(10.55555);
System.out.println("Round down");
System.out.println(format.format(toFormat)); // 10.5555

format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
toFormat = BigDecimal.valueOf(10.55555);
System.out.println("Round up");
System.out.println(format.format(toFormat)); // 10.5556
```

Comment: Note that Java allows underscore in number literals. Using them to mark the point for rounding may help readers through the bunch of `5`s…

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer since the behaviour seemed correct to me. This would be issue [JDK-7131459](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7131459). However it seems it should have been [backported in 7u40](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8000978) so why does it occur with 7u80? Or maybe this was a different bug?

Comment: The DecimalFormat class does not say if it will work on the exact or the canonical representation of the double (unless I missed it) so both behaviours seem acceptable...

Answer (score 5):

The change of behaviour is documented in [the release notes of Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)

> When using the `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat` classes, the rounding behavior of previous versions of the JDK was wrong in some corner cases. [...]
>
> As an example, when using the default recommended `NumberFormatFormat` API form: `NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance()` followed by `nf.format(0.8055d)`, the value 0.8055d is recorded in the computer as 0.80549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625 since this value cannot be represented exactly in the binary format. Here, the default rounding rule is "half-even", and the result of calling format() in JDK 7 is a wrong output of "0.806", while the correct result is "0.805", since the value recorded in memory by the computer is "below" the tie.
>
> This new behavior is also implemented for all rounding positions that might be defined by any pattern chosen by the programmer (non default patterns).