# Java BigDecimal Issue

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to convert String "0.955000" to "0.96" using Java DecimalFormat

Here's my code snippet:

```
String inputVal = "0.955000";
DecimalFormat decFmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00")
decFmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String outputVal = decFmt.format(Double.valueof(inputVal));
```

Here I get the output value as "0.95".
I was expecting output to be "0.96". Does anyone know what's wrong in my code?
And is there a way, I can get "0.96" using decimal format.

Comment: Your title talk about an issue with `BigDecimal`, but your code doesn't use it. With what do you need help?

Comment: To tack onto @Tunaki 's answer, if you were using BigDecimal, you could use the `.setScale(..)` method and accomplish what you want.

Comment: Ahem, `double` precision.

Comment: Why using `DecimalFormat` to perform the rounding which `BigDecimal` supports this directly.  If you want to do your own rounding you may as well use `double`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RoundingMode.HALF\_DOWN issue in Java8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778927/roundingmode-half-down-issue-in-java8)

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I tried:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String inputVal      = "0.955000";
    DecimalFormat decFmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    decFmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    String outputVal = decFmt.format(Double.valueOf(inputVal));
    System.out.println(outputVal);
  }
}
```

The output I got using jdk 7 is 0.96 but with jdk 8 I got 0.95.

Here is why: 0.955 as double is: 0.9549999833106995 in IEEE binary format

The round half up will become: 0.95 which is the correct answer.

Comment: I get 0.95 when I run your code using 1.8.0_40

Comment: This is similar to the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778927/roundingmode-half-down-issue-in-java8

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Got the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue with this. Earlier I was trying with Java 7 and was getting 0.96. Now after changing to Java 8, I got it as 0.95. I thinks it's a Java version issue. Java 7 and 8 are behaving differently for Decimal Format.

Comment: The correct output is 0.95 and not 0.96 this is because the double is stored in IEEE binary format. See my update above