# Confused by DecimalFormat/RoundingMode.Down functionality for edge cases

Tags: java, floating-point, decimalformat

Based on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778927/roundingmode-half-down-issue-in-java8), I would expect the following to print out 0.59 and not 0.60.

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double toFormat = 0.6;
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("########0.00");
        formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(toFormat)); // 0.60
    }
}
```

The closest floating point representation of 0.60 is 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, which is below 0.6. With DecimalFormat set to RoundingMode.DOWN in Java 8, why isn't this rounded down to 0.59?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the formatting code is aware of the precision of a `double`.

See comment in [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/text/DigitList.java#l448) of method `shouldRoundUp(...)` in class `java.text.DigitList`:

> To avoid erroneous double-rounding or truncation when converting
>   a binary double value to text, information about the exactness
>   of the conversion result in FloatingDecimal, as well as any
>   rounding done, is needed in this class.
>
> - For the  HALF_DOWN, HALF_EVEN, HALF_UP rounding rules below:
>     In the case of formating float or double, We must take into
>     account what FloatingDecimal has done in the binary to decimal
>     conversion.
>
>   Considering the tie cases, FloatingDecimal may round-up the
>     value (returning decimal digits equal to tie when it is below),
>     or "truncate" the value to the tie while value is above it,
>     or provide the exact decimal digits when the binary value can be
>     converted exactly to its decimal representation given formating
>     rules of FloatingDecimal ( we have thus an exact decimal
>     representation of the binary value).
>
>   - If the double binary value was converted exactly as a decimal
>       value, then DigitList code must apply the expected rounding
>       rule.
>   - If FloatingDecimal already rounded up the decimal value,
>       DigitList should neither round up the value again in any of
>       the three rounding modes above.
>   - If FloatingDecimal has truncated the decimal value to
>       an ending '5' digit, DigitList should round up the value in
>       all of the three rounding modes above.
>
>   This has to be considered only if digit at maximumDigits index
>     is exactly the last one in the set of digits, otherwise there are
>     remaining digits after that position and we don't have to consider
>     what FloatingDecimal did.
> - Other rounding modes are not impacted by these tie cases.
> - For other numbers that are always converted to exact digits
>     (like BigInteger, Long, ...), the passed alreadyRounded boolean
>     have to be  set to false, and allDecimalDigits has to be set to
>     true in the upper DigitList call stack, providing the right state
>     for those situations..