# Java: vertical scaling with more threads vs more JVMs

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

New to Java, coming from python where GIL prevents true multithreading for cpu-intensive work

Say I have a multithreaded Java program with 100 threads on a 48-core/190GB RAM machine. when I look at the host resource utilizations, it rarely go above load of 1 but memory usage is around 50GB

Are there any cases where simply increasing the thread count on the JVM is not scalable, that launching an additional JVM with the same amount of threads achieve more throughput/parallelism/cpu/io-bound work?

Vertically scaling (A) One JVM w/ 100 threads

to

(B) One JVM w/ 100+N threads or (C) N JVMs w/ 100 threads

I am trying to understand if there are cases where B is better than C and vice versa

Comment: splitting your task in several JVMs only makes communication between threads harder.

Comment: Not sure how much [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549938/4121573) is still valid, but that would be an argument to have N JVMs over 1 JVM

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov assume communications need to only happend at the 100 threads level ie in the case of (C) theads from another JVMs do not need to talk to each other

Comment: Different JVMs means also when processor switches from one thread to another, most likely it is a thread from different JVM and so different O/S process, so all the registers which control virtual memory must be reloaded, which also takes time. On the other hand, garbage collection may take less time because of less amout of controlled memory - or it may take more time because of greater number of JVMs. Anyway, the difference should be measured, and it can change over time.